# How do I change nodal coordinates in a 2D mesh without changing anything else?

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I have a 2D mesh that I generated via `ToElementMesh`.  It discretizes a square domain with a small hole whose shape comes from a parametric B-spline.  I now want to change the shape of the hole very very slightly and produce a new mesh identical in every respect to the original, except that (*only*) the coordinates of nodes on the hole are changed.  The change is small enough so that I do not have to worry about excessive element distortion.  Is there any way to update `"Coordinates"` in the mesh "object"  without changing anything else in it?

I tried to build the new mesh manually by extracting  `"Coordinates"` and `"MeshElements"` from the original.  For instance,

```
XC = meshoriginal["Coordinates"];
ME = meshoriginal["MeshElements"];
meshupdated = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> XC, "MeshElements" -> ME];
```

changes many properties in `meshupdated`, which I want to keep the same as in `meshoriginal` (e.g., `"BoundaryElements"` and several other properties change);

The purpose of this is to compute a finite difference estimate of the gradient of the response with respect to the B-spline parameters.

I apologize in advance if my question does not conform to this forum standards.  It's the first time I ask a question. Thanks!

Comment: It's always good to post complete working code that can be cut and pasted to reproduce exactly what you have. The answers will be better - even in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
newcoords = updatecoords[XC];
meshupdated = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> newcoords, "MeshElements" -> ME,
                            "BoundaryElements" -> meshoriginal["BoundaryElements"],
                            "PointElements" -> meshoriginal["PointElements"]];
```

That can be sped up (if you are absolutely sure the structure of the mesh did not change) by giving options changing the options of `ElementMesh`:

```
Options[ElementMesh]
{"CheckIncidentsCompletness" -> True, 
 "CheckIntersections" -> Automatic, "CheckQuality" -> Automatic, 
 "DeleteDuplicateCoordinates" -> True, "MessageHead" -> Automatic}
```

to

```
opts = {"CheckIncidentsCompletness" -> False, "CheckIntersections" -> False, 
        "CheckQuality" -> Automatic, "DeleteDuplicateCoordinates" -> False, 
        "MessageHead" -> Automatic}
```

and give that to `ToElementMesh[...., opts]`